# What does the flange do over that rectangular cavity antenna?

Tags: antenna

I'd like to know what does this flange contribute to the rectangular cavity just below the flange.

I assume it's to reduce side effects, what else are the contributions the flange does to the cavity?

What's meant by infinite flange and finite flange?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Mechanical Interfacing with a waveguide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flange around a cavity-backed aperture antenna has a significant effect on the radiation pattern. If the flange dimensions are large compared to the wavelength, it can be approximated as going on to infinity, which makes mathematical analysis simpler. If the flange is around a wavelength or less, you need one of numerical simulation programs. Roughly speaking though, the infinite flange gives a narrower beam, and the narrower flange gives a broader beam.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer